# How to sum amount and group by date range in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have two tables in db order and budget. The budget has many orders. The order table has two columns: amount and order_date.  I want to define a date range for example one week and a start date. Then I want to receive for each budget amount with columns date range in psql.

Example:
orders

```
----------------------------------------
| id | amount | budget_id | order_date |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |   20   |     1     | 26.06.2021 |
________________________________________ 
|  2 |   15   |     1     | 27.06.2021 |
----------------------------------------
|  3 |   15   |     2     | 27.06.2021 |
----------------------------------------
|  4 |   25   |     3     | 02.07.2021 |
----------------------------------------
```

budgets:

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
|  1 |  b1  |
_____________
|  2 |  b2  |
_____________
|  3 |  b3  |
_____________
```

output:

```
--------------------------------------------
|budget_name| 21.06 - 27.06 | 28.06 - 04.07|
--------------------------------------------
|   b1      |      35       |       0      |
--------------------------------------------
|   b2      |      15       |       0      |
--------------------------------------------
|   b3      |       0       |       25     |
--------------------------------------------
```

data range columns should be generated to the last date.